# How to cast a List<TBase> to a List<TChild> using reflection (not using Linq Cast<>)?

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, casting

I have a variable of `List<Tbase>`. I know that all items in it are of `TChild`. I have this `TChild` type only as a variable similar to `var t = typeof(TChild)`.

So I tried:

```
                     var elementType = param.ParameterType.GenericTypeArguments.First();
                     var values = value.Select(x => Dynamic.InvokeConvert(x, elementType, true)).ToList();
```

Yet It gives type `'System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Object]'` white I need it to be of target type.

So how to cast a `List<TBase>` to a `List<TChild>` using reflection (not using Linq `Cast<>`)?

Comment: Are you expecting to see a `List<TChild>` at compile-time? If so, there is no way to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an instance of `List<>`, constructed with `elementType`, first:

```cs
dynamic list = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(elementType));
foreach(dynamic val in value)
{
    list.Add(val);
}
```

`dynamic` will perform the remaining lookup.